# Using Webpack's `dependOn` with multiple files per entry

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

The [webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/#dependencies) state that you can use `dependOn` in combination with an array of files for each entry. Here's the example they give:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  entry: {
    app: { import: ['./app.js', './app2.js'], dependOn: 'react-vendors' },
    'react-vendors': ['react', 'react-dom', 'prop-types']
  }
};
```

In my application I have two page-specific assets that both depend on a "common" pack, so I use the above approach

NOTE: Webpack supports mixing SCSS and JS files via the [`MiniCssExtractPlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/)

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  
  'entry': {
    'common': [
      `${ASSETS_DIR}/javascript/packs/common.js`,
      `${ASSETS_DIR}/stylesheets/packs/common.scss`
    ],

    'pageOne': {
      'import': [
        `${ASSETS_DIR}/javascript/packs/pageOne.js`,
        `${ASSETS_DIR}/stylesheets/packs/pageOne.scss`
      ],
      'dependOn': 'common'
    },

    'pageTwo': {
      'import': [
        `${ASSETS_DIR}/javascript/packs/pageTwo.js`,
        `${ASSETS_DIR}/stylesheets/packs/pageTwo.scss`
      ],
      'dependOn': 'common'
    }

  }
}
```

However I receive an error that my configuration is incorrect:

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.entry should be one of these:
   function | object { <key>: non-empty string | [non-empty string] } | non-empty string | [non-empty string]
   -> The entry point(s) of the compilation.
   Details:
    * configuration.entry['pageTwo'] should be a string.
      -> The string is resolved to a module which is loaded upon startup.
    * configuration.entry['pageTwo'] should be an array:
      [non-empty string]
      -> A non-empty array of non-empty strings
    * configuration.entry['pageTwo'] should be one of these:
      [non-empty string]
      -> All modules are loaded upon startup. The last one is exported.
    * configuration.entry['pageTwo'] should be one of these:
      non-empty string | [non-empty string]
      -> An entry point with name
```

**Any reason why Webpack doesn't like this configuration format?**

Here's the versions I'm using:

```
$ cat package.json | grep webpack
    ....

    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.8.2"
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.5",
    "webpack": "^4.41.2",
    "webpack-assets-manifest": "^3.1.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.9"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I didn't realize that Webpack v5 was recently released. At the time of this writing, it's still in beta, so I didn't realize the docs had officially switched over to v5 already.

Looking at the same functionality on the [v4 docs](https://v4.webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#prevent-duplication), it doesn't seem to support multiple files per entry in the same way.

So the answer is to upgrade to v5 for this feature.